# Parameters needed for talking to an HTML web form

Tags: html, forms, field

Please view the page linked below to understand the question.

http://forecast.weather.gov/zipcity.php

How would I go about finding the name of that city/state/zip text input field?

I need to allow a user to enter the city, state or zip into my own text field and then submit that to the above website's form but I don't know how to specify that specific field.

Comment: why did you tag this as Android???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?CityName=City&state=ST(ate)`

http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?CityName=Tucson&state=AZ

Comment: I know this is old but for anyone finding this on Google an alternative parameter is inputstring. For example: http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?inputstring=zip or ...?inputstring=city,+state

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you download firebug for firefox - it makes analyzing web pages vastly easier.  Until then, you'll just have to look through the page source by hand.

But yes, the name of the field is 'inputstring'